# Selecting independent objects using GeoJSON on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I'm working with OpenLayers and loading a couple of GEOJson files which works perfectly. Now I want to be able to select individual components of the GEOJson file. As for example if I have more than one Feature (a couple of polygons) when I activate the hover selection, nothing happens.

I added the hover selector to this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/geojson.html

I can actually drag the elements independently but I can't select them. I assume it is because of the projection I'm using. Any Ideas how to fix it?

```
function init(){

var options = {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    units: "m",
    numZoomLevels: 18,
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options );
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM({layers: 'basic'});           
map.addLayer(mapnik);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

var lon = 12.18;
var lat = 53.81;
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(map.displayProjection,  map.projection);

var mapcent = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection);
zoom = 5.5;
map.setCenter(mapcent, zoom);
document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;

var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

var file = [];
file[0] = "geojson/nuts3.geojson";

var style = [];

i=0;
while(i<file.length){
    style[i] = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        pointRadius: 2,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    });

    var layer_name = "layer_" + i;
    vectorLayer[i] = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(layer_name,  {
        styleMap: style[i],
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        preFeatureInsert: function(feature){
        feature.geometry.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
        },
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer[i]);   

    var gjson = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    var featurecollection = ReadFile(file[i]);
    //Readfile is just a normal Request.POST function   
    vectorLayer[i].addFeatures(gjson.read(featurecollection));  
    i=i+1;
}

controls = {
    selecthover: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer[0],{
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true
    })
};

for(var key in controls) {
    map.addControl(controls[key]);
    controls[key].activate();

}

            var report = function(e) {
            OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id);
        };

        var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectors, {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            renderIntent: "temporary",
            eventListeners: {
                beforefeaturehighlighted: report,
                featurehighlighted: report,
                featureunhighlighted: report
            }
        });


        map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
        map.addControl(selectCtrl);            
}
```

The geojson file looks something like

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 9.244170, 48.847009 ], [ 9.246171, 48.822260 ], [ 9.248220, 48.796910 ], [ 9.248433, 48.794277 ], [ 9.290007, 48.791633 ], [ 9.298732, 48.785304 ],  [ 9.145165, 48.859655 ], [ 9.153553, 48.861241 ], [ 9.207493, 48.852769 ], [ 9.235667, 48.848344 ], [ 9.244170, 48.847009 ] ] ] } }
  ,
  { "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon",   "coordinates": [ [ [ 9.064848, 48.755577 ], [ 9.038994, 48.741317 ], [ 9.104720, 48.709080 ], [ 9.104721, 48.709079 ], [ 9.146561, 48.663574 ], [ 9.156822, 48.652414 ], [ 9.162166, 48.646602 ], [ 9.174173, 48.633544 ],  [ 9.064848, 48.755577 ] ] ] } }
,
```

... etc

Comment: do you have unique ids for you polygons?

Comment: yes. I generated the geojson file with QGIS so all the elements have independent ids and properties.

Comment: I tried and it works if you add the elements as independent featurecollections. However, this doesn't represent a very useful solution considering big files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I Solved it.

[Change vector projection in Openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/change-vector-projection-in-openlayers)

Following the projection proposed in the right answer of that question and using independent id's for each part of the geojson file it is possible to select on hover.